# how to use bincode operator in group function in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to group below data on fname and lastname.

(fname,lname,id)

```
abc,xyz,I
abc,xyz,N
ppp,xxx,I
ppp,XXX,I
```

in id field i am expecting only 2 values i.e N or I so if I get both N and I for same fname,lname combination then I should use id as N else need to use value for id field as it is given in the group.

I am expecting below results:

```
abc,xyz,N
ppp,xxx,I
```

I have tried below code and its working fine

```
in =load '/testing/name.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (fname:chararray,lname:chararray,id:chararray);

grp = group in by (fname,lname);

z = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group) AS (fname,lname),(COUNT(in.id) >1 ? ('N') :BagToTuple(in.id))as id;
```

However now I need to check the values of id field instead of counts:

```
z = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group) AS (fname,lname),((in.id == 'N' or in.id == 'I') ? ('N') :BagToTuple(in.id))as id;
```

however its giving below error:

```
(Name: Equal Type: null Uid: null)incompatible types in Equal Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(id:chararray)  right hand side:chararray
```

however its giving below error:

```
Two inputs of BinCond must have compatible schemas. left hand side: #31:tuple(#32:chararray) right hand side: org.apache.pig.builtin.bagtotuple_3#35:tuple(id#36:int)
```

Please guide

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086768/pig-filter-returns-empty-bag-that-i-cant-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading a field that contains chars i.e. N,I into int column? Change the load statement where id column type is chararray.

```
in =load '/testing/name.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (fname:chararray,lname:chararray,id:chararray);
grp = group in by (fname,lname);
z = foreach grp generate FLATTEN(group) AS (fname,lname),(COUNT(in.id) > 1 && in.id matches 'N') ? ('N') : in.id;
```

Comment: change BagToTuple(in.id)) as id to in.id as id